# newDate() function in javascript converting to CDT

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, datetime-format

I'm calling the below function to format date from API Response. In the response if the date comes as "2021-10-02", the new date() converts it to Mon oct 01 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) which is one day before. In UI, I'm not getting the exact date that is coming in response. How to convert to CST Timezone back?

```
applyFormat(date){
        var day = new Date(date);
        var dd = day.getDate();
        var mm = day.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = day.getFullYear();
        var theDay = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        return theDay;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date('2021-10-02")` will create a date as midnight GMT, on the given date - it's part of the spec  - however `new Date('2021-10-02T00:00:00')` will create a date given the time in YOUR timezone

You have two options:

```js
function applyFormat(date) {
  var day = new Date(date+'T00:00:00');
  return day.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
}
console.log(applyFormat('2021-10-02'))
```

Or simply don't use Date object at all

```js
function applyFormat(date) {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-').map(Number)
  var theDay = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  return theDay;
}
console.log(applyFormat('2021-10-02'))
```

Or if you really want to use the Date object

```js
function applyFormat(date) {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-').map((v, i) => +v-(i%2))
  const day = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  return day.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
}
console.log(applyFormat('2021-10-02'))
```

Comment: _"`+v-(i%2)`"_ 

Comment: @Phil - yes, makes `v` a number, and subtracts 1, for the month only, to use in new Date  - perfectly efficient code :p - of course, in my code, I do `.map(($,_)=>+$-(_%2))` to mess with my colleagues :p - or when I'm feeling particularly evil `.map((_,$)=>+_-($%-(~[]+~[])))`

Comment: more bitwise operators... MOAR!

Comment: I'd post how you can make the `.map` something like `[...]` instead ... but it's 1,756 characters long :p - jsf*ck :p